# Cassandra 1.x and proper JNA setup

Tags: cassandra

is there any documentation about proper JNA configuration?

I do not understand few things:

1) Does JNA use JVM heap settings?

2) Do I need to decrease max heap size while using JNA?

3) How do I limit RAM allocated by JNA?

4) Where can I see / monitor row cache size?

5) I've configured JNA just for test on my dev computer and so far
I've noticed serious performance issues (high cpu usage on heavy write
load), so I must be doing something wrong.... I've just copied JNA
jars into Cassandra/lib, without installing any native libs. 
Thanks,
Maciej

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking specifically about JNA-based row caches.

1) No

2) Yes, other things being equal

3) By configuring the row cache size appropriately

4) JMX on ColumnFamilyStoreMBeans

5) the off-heap cache uses *less* CPU under writes than the in-heap one (it just invalidates updated rows, instead of updating them in a write-through fashion) so I'd say something else is wrong.  Be sure to rule out swapping because of (2).

Comment: Cassandra serializes whole row into RAM using malloc from JNA - this is fine. For off heap row cache I need to decrease JVM heap, otherwise server might start swapping. I also really need to cheerfully calculate row size, there is no way to limit RAM allocated by off heap cache. Is there possibility to find out amount of RAM being used by off heap cache?

Comment: cache size ~= rows cached * average row size.  this is actually a *better* situation than with the on-heap cache where you have rows cached * average row size * per-row JVM overhead which varies depending on your data.